# What is the C++ equivalent of python's import as?

Tags: c++, reference

I've tried several variations of this with no joy...

```
auto& hrctp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;
auto& hrcn = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
```

I know I can use...

```
use namespace std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
```

And I understand one shouldn't try too hard to replicate the paradigms of one language in another but I'm just curious. Is there an equivalent?

Comment: [Kinda sorta](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/namespace_alias).

Comment: [`using hrtcp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias)

Comment: In C++ aliasing is different for types and functions and namespaces. `time_point` is a type, so you can define an alias with `using`. `now` is a static function, you can define an alias as a reference.

Comment: @legends2k : He already *says* he knows how to rename namespaces!  The point is he wants to rename a type and a function.

Comment: @legends2k: With a reference you can't ordinarily see any difference so it's pretty much a genuine alias. But with a `typedef` or `using` the defined name can't be used to define a destructor or constructor, and it can be used in a pseudo-destructor call, so it's not quite a genuine alias. Other than that I think it depends on one's definition of "genuine" :)

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I think that would make a good answer. If you commented back that you wrote it up, I'd give you a +1 ;)

Comment: @JonathanMee That comment is incomplete. It doesn't answer how to alias functions.

Comment: @MartinBonner My bad. Retracted the vote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more complex than it looks.  As [Cheers and hth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464581/cheers-and-hth-alf) says, aliasing is different for types and functions and namespaces.

For a simple type like `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point`, you can either use `typedef` or `using`:

```
using hrctp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;
```

or

```
typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point hrctp;
```

The advantage of `using` is that you can use it for template classes too.

For a static member function or a stand-alone function embedded in a namespace, you can just use a pointer to the function:

```
const auto hrcn = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
```

You can't do this for non-static member functions (a pointer-to-member-function is a completely different beast), but fortunately you don't need to (because you invoke non-static member functions on an object of the appropriate type).

---

The options for `time_point` are purely done at compile time.  However the function alias may impose a run-time penalty (because you are calling the function through a pointer, rather than jumping there directly).  However, write your code for clarity first, and speed second.  (OTOH, the C++ way would probably be:

```
using hrc =std::chrono::high_resolution_clock;
```

and then use `hrc::time_point` and `hrc::now`.

Comment: Great answer Martin, thanks. And thanks for the style tip too!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to define an alias, use a [`using`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) directive. That means this would work:

```
using hrctp = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;
```

For the function, you could use something like this:

```
const auto hrcn = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
```

This creates a function pointer to the static function.

Comment: Except that `now` is a function, and you can't use `using` to define an alias for a function.

Comment: @MartinBonner Fixed

Answer (score 2):

It's simple.  Short answer... It's different for types and functions.

```
// Alias the type...
using hr_time_point = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point;

// Create reference (like an alias) for the function
auto &hr_now = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now;
```

The compiler will undoubtedly optimize away the reference, and call the referent directly.

This would work equally well:

```
inline auto hr_now() { return std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now(); }
```

Again, the optimizer will optimize out the indirection.